# Docker embed commands usage on Windows

Tags: windows, docker

I'm running `Docker v 17.09.0-ce` on `Windows 10`.
When I try to run embed commands like this:
`docker restart $(docker ps -a)` it throws me the error:
`unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a)`. Without the `-a` flag the error looks like this:

```
Error response from daemon: No such container: $(docker
Error response from daemon: No such container: ps)
```

These kind of embed commands suggestions are widespread across the web. How do I make it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$(docker ps -a)` is a bash syntax (along with other common shells on Linux). To use this syntax on a Windows system, you need to use a bash shell rather than the powershell or command prompt.

Comment: Yes, the windows command would be bash. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about

Answer (score 0):

`docker restart $(docker ps -a)` wouldn't work on Linux either. I think you're looking for `docker restart $(docker ps -aq)` (with "quiet" flag) - this works great in Powershell too.